# Oracle Custom Web Interface (ASP.NET, C#) - Getting DBMS_OUTPUT contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I'm writing a customized, simple Web interface for Oracle DB, using ASP.NET, a Web API project in C#, and Oracle.DataAccess (ODP.NET). This is an educational project which I am designing for an extra project for a college course. There's several reasons for me designing this project, but the upshot is that using Oracle-provided tools (SQL Developer, Enterprise Manage Express, etc.) are not suitable for the task at hand.

I have an API call that can accept a query string, execute it against the DBMS and return the DBMS's output as JSON data, along with some additional return data. This has been sufficient for simple SELECT queries and other basic DDL/DML queries. However, now we're branching into PL/SQL.

For example, the most basic PL/SQL HELLO WORLD program that we'd execute looks like:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World');
END;
```

When I feed this query into my C# API, it does execute successfully. However, I want to be able to retrieve the output of the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE call(s).

This question has been addressed before and I have looked into a few of the solutions, and came down on one involving a piece of code which calls the following PL/SQL on the database:

```
BEGIN 
    Dbms_output.get_line(:line, :status);
END;
```

The C# code obviously creates and adds the correct parameter objects to the request before sending it. I plan to call this function repeatedly until a NULL value comes back, indicating the end of output. This data would then be added to the JSON object returned by the API so that the Web interface can display the output. However, this function never returns any lines of output.

My hunch (I'm still learning Oracle myself, so not sure) is that either the server isn't actually outputting the data, or that the buffer is flushed after the PL/SQL anonymous procedure (the Hello World) program finishes.

It was also suggested to add `set serveroutput on;` to the PL/SQL query but this did not work: it produced the error `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`.

Here is the actual C# code being used to retrieve a line of output from the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer:

```
private string GetDbmsOutputLine(OracleConnection conn)
{
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand
    {
        CommandText = "begin dbms_output.get_line(:line, :status); end;",
        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
        Connection = conn,
    };

    OracleParameter lineParameter = new OracleParameter("line",
        OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    lineParameter.Size = 32000;
    lineParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command.Parameters.Add(lineParameter);

    OracleParameter statusParameter = new OracleParameter("status",
        OracleDbType.Int32);
    statusParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command.Parameters.Add(statusParameter);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (command.Parameters["line"].Value is DBNull)
        return null;

    string line = command.Parameters["line"].Value as string;

    return line;
}
```

---

Edit: I tried manually calling the following procedure prior to executing the user's code: `BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(32768); END;`. This executes without error but after doing so the later calls to `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE` still return null.

It looks like what may be happening is that each time I execute a new query to the database, even though it's on the same connection, that the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer is being cleared. I am not sure if this is the case, but it seems to be - nothing else would readily explain the lack of data in the buffer.

Still searching for a way to handle this...

Points to keep in mind:

- This is an academic project for student training and development; hence, it is not expected that this mini-application be "production-ready" in any way. Allowing users to execute raw queries posted via the Web obviously leads to all sorts of security risks - which is why this would never be put into an actual production scenario.
- I currently open a connection and maintain it throughout a single API call by passing it into each `OracleCommand` object I create. This, in theory, should mean that the buffer is maintained, but it doesn't appear to be the case. Either the data I write is not making it to the buffer in the first place, or the buffer is flushed each time an `OracleCommand` object is actually executed against the database connection.

Comment: You know, right, that real production code would never, ever rely on `dbms_output`, right?  That's useful for developers to do some very basic debugging.  But you should never write code that assumes that anyone will ever see what you've written to the `dbms_output` buffer.  Are you returning data this way because you can't return it properly as output parameters?  Or because you think reasonable people output useful information using `dbms_output`?

Comment: Yes, fully understood. As I said this is for a college course and is strictly designed for a learning environment. With rare exceptions one would also never put into production a system allowing raw queries to be executed via the Web. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that in reality you'd never write code that expects that anyone will ever see data that you attempt to write to the `dbms_output`...

Within a session, you'd need to call [`dbms_output.enable`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABGBACJ) that allocates the buffer that is written to by `dbms_output`.  Depending on the Oracle version, you may be able to pass in a `null` to indicate that you want an unlimited buffer size.  In older versions, you'd need to allocate a fixed buffer size (and you'd get an error if you try to write too much data to the buffer).  Then you'd call the procedure that calls `dbms_output.put[_line]`.  Finally, you'd be able to call `dbms_output.get[_line]`.  Note that all three things have to happen in the context of a single session.  Each session has a separate `dbms_output` buffer (or no `dbms_output` buffer).

Comment: I think this partly answers my question - that each call to the database engine will clear the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer. I am maintaining a connection object between calls, but I am submitting separate queries as seen above to attempt to retrieve the output. I could possibly prepend and append calls to get the data...but this would then eliminate the actual table results from the output. Is there perhaps a way to return more than one thing from a PL/SQL program? i.e. the result of a SELECT query as well as an array of lines from DBMS_OUTPUT?

Comment: @fdmillion - Each call doesn't flush the buffer.  Each session allocates (or doesn't allocate) a private buffer.  Multiple calls within that session will write to (or read from) the same buffer. If you have any sort of connection pooling going on, be aware that most connection pools don't reset the buffer so you could read data that some other connection wrote if you happen to get unlucky (or unless you override the connection pool's behavior). You can certainly modify the signature of the procedure that you're calling to have a `sys_refcursor` and some sort of collection as output parameters.